# Are fibered categories fibrant objects in some model structure on Cat/C?

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-categories

Given a category $\mathcal{C}$, by a category over $\mathcal{C}$, I mean a category $\mathcal{D}$ along with a functor $\pi_{\mathcal{D}}:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$.

Consider the category $Cat/C$, of categories over $\mathcal{C}$. I am assuming the familiarity with the notion of a fibered category over $\mathcal{C}$ (if not, please see Definition 3.5 of Angelo Vistoli's [Notes on Grothendieck topologies,fibered categoriesand descent theory](http://homepage.sns.it/vistoli/descent.pdf)).

Question is the following:

- Is there a (interesting/non-trivial) model structure on $Cat/\mathcal{C}$, in which fibered categories are the fibrant objects?

Or, are the terms "fibered category" and "fibrations" just two unrelated terms that sound same?

Comment: I think the terminology represents "two unrelated terms that sound the same" since both are kinda inspired by fibrations in topological spaces (like, for every point in the base space there is a fiber above it). That said, the answer to your question could still be "yes" and I'm curious to see if anyone knows.

Comment: Please check https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110247.pdf (A homotopy theory for stacks by Sharon Hollander)

Comment: Also check https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.06129.pdf (Categorical notions of fibration) by Loregian and Riehl

Comment: The inclusion of fibered categories over $C$ into $Cat/C$ has a left 2-adjoint given by $(D \to C) \mapsto D \downarrow C$, and in fact is [2-monadic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2422803/the-2-monad-for-grothendieck-fibrations). Even better, the resulting 2-monad is [lax-idempotent](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lax-idempotent+2-monad). If the 2-monad were idempotent, we'd have a reflective subcategory, and thus a model structure in a sort of degenerate way. As it is, I'm not sure... For the $\infty$-categorical context, see [Barwick and Shah](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04343).

Comment: @DavidWhite Hi. I also think the answer is “yes”. Hope some one responds. :)

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri Thanks for the second reference. First reference I saw long back. Did not read it after that :D Your comment might be sufficient motivation to read that paper.. They fix a Grothendieck topology on $\mathcal{C}$, which might be very different from the category with out such choice.

Comment: @TimCampion Hi. I do not completely understand which question does the paper by Barwick and Shah answers :O May be you are assuming I know more things :) can you please elaborate a little bit.

Comment: The Barwick and Shah paper is meant to simply address the idea that there is _some_ relationship between different notions of "fibration", including model-categorical ones, as well as categorical fibrations, i.e. fibered categories.

Comment: @TimCampion Oh, thank you. I will see that paper :)

Comment: Is any retract in $\mathbf{Cat}/C$ of a fibered category over $C$ a fibered category over $C$?

Comment: One concrete issue, related to @TimCampion's first comment, is that the "inclusion" of fibered categories into $\mathit{Cat}/C$ is not full: the "natural" choice of morphism between fibered categories is a functor that preserves cartesian arrows.  This is not generally what happens for the fibrant objects in a model category.

Comment: BTW, I presume that you meant to ask for a model structure in which fibered categories are _the_ fibrant objects; i.e., such that a category over $C$ is fibered iff it is fibrant.  There is of course a model structure in which fibered categories are fibrant objects, but not every fibrant object is a fibered category: the slice model structure induced from the canonical model structure on $\mathit{Cat}$.

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell “Is any retract in / of a fibered category over  a fibered category over ” looks more than a comment and less than an answer :) Thanks, did not thought about it. I will think and respond.

Comment: @MikeShulman yes, I mean fibered categories are the fibrant objects. I should have written it more clearly. Editing it now.

Comment: Also BTW, your last sentence presents a false dichotomy.  Even if there is no model structure in which the fibered categories are the fibrant objects, that doesn't mean the terms are entirely *unrelated*.  (-:

Comment: @MikeShulman Is that so? I do not know, your comment looks both positive and negative at the same time :)